# com_users login format view?

Tags: php, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I would like to know what this code does in the joomla file

> components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/**default_login.php**

```
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('credentials') as $field): ?>
<?php if (!$field->hidden): ?>
```

Also, how do I add the "remember me" option that is given with the login module?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('credentials') as $field): ?>
```

This section will get the all the fields from the "credentials" fieldset stored in:

> components/com_users/models/forms/login.xml

---

```
<?php if (!$field->hidden): ?>
```

If the field being processed on the loop is not hidden .... then... it will be displayed I guess.

---

Regarding the "remember me" option, you can find a solution in the joomla forum:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=695612

Comment: So would it be okay for me to remove those lines? As I would like to load the labels and fields seperately, and to do that I need to remove, the foreach statement, which makes the second line of code useless in effect.

Comment: IMO you shouldn't modify the core files (even if it's a view), you should override the layout and there you can remove those lines and customize your view at  your will.

Comment: Yep this is an override I am doing. But I'm unsure if it's okay to remove those two lines?

Comment: It's OK :) as long as you use the same fieldnames... or well, it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: Oh okay. I need to load the fields seperately so I can control their layout more. I have loaded the fields from the module instead: `<label for="modlgn-username"><?php echo JText::_('COM_USERS_LOGIN_USERNAME_LABEL') ?></label>
  <input id="modlgn-username" type="text" name="username" class="inputbox"  size="18" /> ` Is that method okay, or should I load them from the com_user folder?

Comment: If you are using that code is seems to be ok. It's using the same value in name.